# "Syntax error at or near END" with column name END

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in MYSQL and have to convert it in postgresql.

I am using the below command to create the table.

```
create table emp(COMPLETE BOOLEAN NOT NULL, END BOOLEAN NOT NULL);
```

the error, I am getting is

> Error at Command Line : 27 Column : 1 Error report - SQL Error: ERROR:
>   syntax error at or near "END"   Position: 45

But if I change the column name END to END1, then it works fine.

```
create table emp(COMPLETE BOOLEAN NOT NULL, END1 BOOLEAN NOT NULL);
```

Please suggest a way through which I can create the name of columnwith END.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`END` is a keyword. (Among other things, it's used in `CASE ... WHEN ... END`). You must quote it to use it as an identifier.

```
create table emp(complete BOOLEAN NOT NULL, "end" BOOLEAN NOT NULL);
```

Note that `"quoted"` identifiers are *case sensitive*, they aren't *case folded* like unquoted identifiers. That's per the SQL standard. For more information, [see the PostgreSQL documentation on lexical structure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

There's a [list of reserved words in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Answer (score 0):

Problem comes when you use keyword as table name. Best way is use some other name.

Answer (score 0):

Please select another name for your column as END is a keyword. And we cannot use column name same as keyword.

Comment: That's not actually true, you *can* use a keyword or reserved word as a column name. I agree that you generally shouldn't, though.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SQL reserved word as a variable name . For maximum portability of your
application between data managers, you should not use any of the reserved words in this list
as file class or variable names. 
you can even use _END ,END1... 
This is a list of the reserved words of SQL.
http://www.tigerlogic.com/tigerlogic/omnis/download/manuals/SQLReservedWords.pdf

Comment: Note that every DBMS adds its own reserved words as well. So if you're really going for portable, you should quote everything, and set all the database products you use to use ANSI quoting mode.